# Please what is wrong with my PostgreSQL Query in Node and Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I would like to add data to two tables in Postgres with one query using CTE. After a user submit data from a form in the frontend, I want my SQL query to auto insert id in table1. Then the same id in table one will be used to create data of table2 in the same transaction. I have the code below but when I run it by submitting values in Postman, I got the error below which indicate the the returned pid is not being used in the second query.

```
Error in transaction error: null value in column "pid" violates not-null constraint
```

See my code below:

```
exports.addPost = (req, res) => {
  db.query('BEGIN', err => {
      if (shouldAbort(err)) return
      const queryPost = 'INSERT INTO table1 (post_type, created_on) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING pid'
      db.query(queryPost, ['keyword', 'now()'], (err, res) => {
        if (shouldAbort(err)) return
        const data = {
        author: req.body.username,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        body: req.body.body,
        category: req.body.category,
        search_volume: req.body.search_volume,
        is_deleted: req.body.is_deleted
      }
      const insertKeywordText = `INSERT INTO table2 (pid, author, title, description, body, category, search_volume, is_deleted, created_on) 
                                   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)`
    const insertKeywordValues = [res.rows.pid, data.username, data.title, data.description, data.body, data.category, data.search_volume, data.is_deleted, 'now()']

        db.query(insertKeywordText, insertKeywordValues, (err, res) => {
          if (shouldAbort(err)) return
          db.query('COMMIT', err => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error committing transaction', err.stack)
            }
            done()
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Assuming `rows` is infact an array, surely `res.rows[0].pid` is what you want? I'm not sure what lib you are using (can you confirm?) but this looks to me that you are hitting the DB numerous times...

Comment: I'm referring to what library you are using to perform the DB queries?

Comment: `db` isn't a native construct therefore it will be coming from a library, which Node library are you using for the PostgreSQL connection? Is it [pg](https://node-postgres.com/)?

Comment: @James I think it's a mistake with the array. It's working now but the username column is returning a null value and the requests continue to send in postman even when the data has already been registered in the database.

Comment: Yeah it's pg library.